# awk - change line if

Tags: awk

How to change a line in a file by command if only immediate  two lines exist

FROM

```
Line1
LineA
OldLine
```

TO

```
Line1
LineA
NewLine
```

Comment: You don't specify how to distinguish the line to be changed

Comment: "if only immediate two lines exist" makes no sense. Did you try to express "if only two *specific* lines immediately *preceding* it, exist"?

Answer (score 1):

Given your very generic input/output here is something that should work.

```
awk '{ 
        if (f == 2) 
        {
           print "NewLine"
           next
        } else if (/Line1/) 
        { 
           f=1 
        } else if (f == 1 && /LineA/)
        {
           f=2
        } else 
        { 
           f=0 
        } 
        print 
     }'
```

In oneliner form.

```
awk '{if (f == 2) { print "NewLine"; next } else if (/Line1/) { f=1 } else if (f == 1 && /LineA/) { f=2 } else { f=0 } print }'
```

Some examples.

```
$ echo -en 'Line1\nLineA\nOldLine'|awk '{if (f == 2) { print "NewLine"; next } else if (/Line1/) { f=1 } else if (f == 1 && /LineA/) { f=2 } else { f=0 } print }'
Line1
LineA
NewLine

$ echo -en 'Line1\nLineB\nOldLine'|awk '{if (f == 2) { print "NewLine"; next } else if (/Line1/) { f=1 } else if (f == 1 && /LineA/) { f=2 } else { f=0 } print }'
Line1
LineB
OldLine
```